# How to Convert String into bytearray(EUC-KR)?

Tags: ios, swift, encode

Hello There i am using swift 5.0 and developing BLE App.

As we have android app there are using default function as below

```
byte nByte[] = Name.getBytes( charsetName: "EUC-KR")
```

**Output of android**

> Value[0] = **32**  Value[1] = **30**  Value[2] = **32**  Value[3] =
> **32**  Value[4] = **31**  Value[5] = **31**  Value[6] = **32**  Value[7] = **37**  Value[8] = **2d**  Value[9] = **c3**  Value[10] =
> **e6** Value[11] = **ba** Value[12] = **cf** Value[13] = **38** Value[14] = **30** Value[15] = **c0** Value[16] = **da** Value[17] =
> **39** Value[18] = **30** Value[19] = **31** Value[20] = **35** Value[21] = **2d** Value[22] = **58** Value[23] = **2d** Value[24] =
> **30** Value[25] = **32** Value[26] = **2d** Value[27] = **31** Value[28] = **32** Value[29] = **31** Value[30] = **32** Value[31] =
> **31** Value[32] = **32** Value[33] = **31** Value[34] = **2e** Value[35] = **54** Value[36] = **58** Value[37] = **54**

We used in iOS different type of string convert as below

*Code 1*

```
let  rawEncoding =  CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.EUC_KR.rawValue))
let encoding =  String.Encoding(rawValue: rawEncoding)
let  strEUCData = "20221127-충북80자9015-X-02-1212121.TXT".data(using:  encoding) ?? Data()
```

**Output of iOS**

> bytes : 38 elements
>
> - 0 : 50
> - 1 : 48
> - 2 : 50
> - 3 : 50
> - 4 : 49
> - 5 : 49
> - 6 : 50
> - 8 : 45
> - 9 : 195
> - 10 : 230
> - 11 : 186
> - 12 : 207
> - 13 : 56
> - 14 : 48
> - 15 : 192
> - 16 : 218
> - 17 : 57
> - 18 : 48
> - 19 : 49
> - 20 : 53
> - 21 : 45
> - 22 : 88
> - 23 : 45
> - 24 : 48
> - 25 : 50
> - 26 : 45
> - 27 : 49
> - 28 : 50
> - 29 : 49
> - 30 : 50
> - 31 : 49
> - 32 : 50
> - 33 : 49
> - 34 : 46
> - 35 : 84
> - 36 : 88
> - 37 : 84

*Code 2*

```
let  strEUCData1 = "20221127-충북80자9015-X-02-1212121.TXT".data(using:  String.Encoding(rawValue: 0x80000940)) ?? Data()
```

All above functions given wrong byte array.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same data. The Android output is in Hex (base 16) number and the iOS output is in decimal (base 10) number:

```
Android (Hex)   iOS (Decimal)
32              50
30              48
32              50
32              50
31              49
31              49
32              50
37              55
2d              45
c3              195
e6              230
ba              186
cf              207
38              56
30              48
c0              192
da              218
39              57
30              48
31              49
35              53
2d              45
58              88
2d              45
30              48
32              50
2d              45
31              49
32              50
31              49
32              50
31              49
32              50
31              49
2e              46
54              84
58              88
54              84
```